Building a std::variant of pointers of types in the alternatives of another std::variant
I'm given a std::variant of several types. I would like to write a trait that gives another std::variant of the pointer of the types of the first.
using MyVariant = std::variant<int, float>;

using MyVariantOfPointers = pointer_of_v<MyVariant>;

such that MyVariantOfPointer is std::variant<int*, float*>.
I tried to play with std::variant_size_v and std::variant_alternative_t but I do not know how to build the new type recursively.

You can use partial specialization to write a trait to solve this.
// General case
template<class T>
struct VariantToPtrVariant;

// Partial specialization when used with std::variant
// Extracts the template arguments from the `std::variant` and 
//  produces a new `std::variant` with those types, with an added `*`
template<class ... T>
struct VariantToPtrVariant<std::variant<T...>> {
    using type = std::variant<T*...>;
};

// Helper variable template
template<class T>
using VariantToPtrVariant_t = typename VariantToPtrVariant<T>::type;

Usage :
using MyVariant = std::variant<int, float>;
using MyVariantOfPointers = VariantToPtrVariant_t<MyVariant>;

Complete example (https://godbolt.org/z/qaTxo4nzc) :
#include <type_traits>
#include <variant>

template<class T>
struct VariantToPtrVariant;

template<class ... T>
struct VariantToPtrVariant<std::variant<T...>> {
    using type = std::variant<T*...>;
};

template<class T>
using VariantToPtrVariant_t = typename VariantToPtrVariant<T>::type;

using MyVariant = std::variant<int, float>;
using MyVariantOfPointers = VariantToPtrVariant_t<MyVariant>;

static_assert(std::is_same_v<MyVariantOfPointers, std::variant<int*, float*>>);



Another solution providing a generic solution: apply any type functor on any type collection:
// Map Template Functor
template<template<class> class Functor, class TCollection>
struct map {};

template<template<class> class Functor, template<class...> class TCollection, class... Types>
struct map<Functor, TCollection<Types...>>
{
    using type = TCollection<Functor<Types> ...>;
};

Usage example:
// Functor to map
template<typename T> using add_pointer_t   = T*;
template<typename T> using add_reference_t = T&;

// Type collection to map on
using MyVariant = std::variant<int, float, double>;
using MyTuple   = std::tuple<MyVariant, int, int>;

// Usage
using MyVariantOfPointers = map_t<add_pointer_t, MyVariant>;
using MyTupleOfPointers   = map_t<add_reference_t, MyTuple>;
static_assert(std::is_same_v<MyVariantOfPointers, std::variant<int*, float*, double*>>);
static_assert(std::is_same_v<MyTupleOfPointers,   std::tuple<std::variant<int, float, double>&, int&, int&>>);

Demo on Compiler Explorer

This one won't obviously work for anything with default template args, like vector for instance. I mean it will transform everything into pointers of course, but that wouldn't be what any sane user could expect. https://godbolt.org/z/43qPzYx4v

Yes obviously. It won't work with bananas also, obviously.
